# Spin operators commutation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, quantum-spin, commutator

Why do the spin operators $ S_{x1}$ and $S_{x2}$ of **two** particles along the $x$-axis  commute i.e $S_{1x}S_{x2}-S_{2x}S_{1x}=0 $ ?

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the Hilbert space for **one** particle. Then, $S_{x}\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ is a bounded, self-adjoint operator. Now, if you want to have the Hilbert space for **two** particles, remember that this is the tensor product, i.e. $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_1\otimes \mathcal{H}_2$ (where $\mathcal{H}_1$ is the Hilbert space of the first and $\mathcal{H}_2$ the Hilbert space of the second particle).

What then is the operator? Let's consider the spin operator $S_{x}^{(1)}\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}_1)$ and $S_{x}^{(2)}\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}_2)$, then the operator for the first particle is $S_{1x}:=S_{x}^{(1)}\otimes 1$ - because it doesn't do anything on the second particle. For the second particle, we have $S_{2x}:=1\otimes S_{x}^{(2)}$, because the second spin operator, only acts on the second particle. As you can easily show, those two commute, since

$$S_{1x}S_{2x}=(S_{x}^{(1)}\otimes 1) \cdot (1\otimes S_{x}^{(2)})=S_{x}^{(1)}\otimes S_{x}^{(2)}=(1\otimes S_{x}^{(2)})\cdot (S_{x}^{(1)}\otimes 1)=S_{2x}S_{1x}$$

In general, every two operators that act on different parts of the system should commute. One simple reason is that the operators should be jointly measurable (because I can just do the measurement on the one particle, while you measure the other).

Comment: 1) why do you impose the constraint that the particles be identical? 2) And if the Hamiltonian contains a term $S_1$$S_2$ where each one of $S_1$ and $S_2$ are vectors, is it possible to measure, say, $S_{1,x}$ without perturbing $S_2$ ?

Comment: 1) I don't need that constraint - I just wanted to avoid cluttering the notation with more labels, because for different particles, I may need different Hilbert spaces. Maybe that was badly phrased, I'll edit that. 2) What is $S_1S_"$? You'll have to tell me where the operators act, otherwise, I can't say anything.

Comment: @Sofia: Now constraint 1) is no longer there. I added more notation, but maybe that actually clarifies, what I want to say.

Comment: To Martin: Do $S_{x,1}$ and $S_{x,2}$ always commute, or only when there is no spin-spin interaction? t seems to me that in the case I mention, one cannot make an intervention on one spin without disturbing the other.

Comment: @Sofia: I think I still don't really understand you. For me, a "spin operator on one particle" is a measuring operator. Then, it's physically necessary that two spin operators are defined similarly to my definition and they must commute. That is: The definition of the operator is completely independent of any Hamiltonian. "Spin-spin interaction" would be something completely different. There, we have operators also acting on the other part, like $S_1\cdot S_2$ acting on one of the two particles if you want. They do not commute with the $S_{1x},S_{2x}$ as defined above.